# Python import failed for qtgui

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, pyqt4, desktop

I'm trying to `import PyQt4.QtGui`but I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mano/PycharmProjects/desktop/first-1.py", line 2, in <module>
    import PyQt4.QtGui
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4.sip'
Error in sys.excepthook:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport_python_hook.py", line 63, in apport_excepthook
    from apport.fileutils import likely_packaged, get_recent_crashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from apport.report import Report
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/report.py", line 30, in <module>
    import apport.fileutils
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/fileutils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from apport.packaging_impl import impl as packaging
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apport/packaging_impl.py", line 24, in <module>
    import apt
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/apt/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    import apt_pkg
ImportError: No module named 'apt_pkg'

Original exception was:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mano/PycharmProjects/desktop/first-1.py", line 2, in <module>
    import PyQt4.QtGui
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt4.sip'
```

Comment: Please include the code that produces this error in your question.

Comment: http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/installation.html